# Reactjs - API data to have clickable elements with `onClick()` attribute

Tags: reactjs

#### Scenario

I am working on a react dashboard and am currently pulling some data from an API call, into a table.

I want the API data to render a clickable element (row) which will have a unique ID, which will in turn be used to trigger another API call for more information on that specific ID, on a separate card on the Main.js page.

#### Background

So far I have the following code to pull the API, this works fine.

*Main.js*

```javascript
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import List from 'List';
import withListLoading from 'withListLoading';

function MyDash(props) {
  const ListLoading = withListLoading(List);

  useEffect(() => {
  setAppState({ loading: true });
      const apiUrl = (`https://example.com/api/summary/`);
      fetch(apiUrl, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((repos) => {
        setAppState({ loading: false, repos: repos.emails });
      });

return (
  <Card>
    <CardHeader><Row><h3>Summary</h3></Row>
    </CardHeader>
    <CardBody>
      <div>
        <ListLoading isLoading={appState.loading} repos={appState.repos} />
      </div>
    </CardBody>
  </Card>
)
} export default MyDash;
```

*List.js*

```javascript
import React from 'react';
import dateFormat from 'dateformat';
import setTable from  'Main';

const List = (props) => {
  const { repos } = props;
  if (!repos || repos.length === 0) return <p>No data available</p>;
  for (var key in repos) {
    return (
   
    <tbody>
      {repos.map((repo) => { 
        return (
          <tr key={repo.value} className='list'>
            <td className='repo-text max-width' >{repo.value} </td>
            <td className='repo-type text-center'>{repo.type}</td>
            <td className='repo-datetime text-center'>{dateFormat(repo.submitted, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss')}</td>
            <td className='repo-score text-center'>{repo.score}</td>
          </tr>
        );}
      )}
    </tbody>
  );}
};
export default List;
```

*withListLoading.js*

```javascript
import React from 'react';

function WithListLoading(Component) {
  return function WihLoadingComponent({ isLoading, ...props }) {
    if (!isLoading) return <Component {...props} />;
    return (
      <p style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: '30px' }}>
        Fetching data may take some time, please wait
      </p>
    );
  };
}; export default WithListLoading;
```

#### What I have tried

- I tried to use `onClick={() => SetMsg("x")}` in the `<tr>` however I received the following error, so am a bit lost for how to architect this, given that the parts are on different pages.

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>
> - See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

```javascript
function SetMsg(id) {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const setCount = (id) => {
      count(id);
      console.log(id);
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: When you change set("x") with alert("x").. does it work?

Comment: @MartinOsusky Yes

Comment: Before render (return) define click event function (e.g. itemClicked()) in which trigger another API call. And call it from row <tr onClick={itemClicked}>.

Comment: Thanks, I think I might be in a little over my head - I set a function as follows `function SetMsg(id) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  count(id);
  console.log(id);
}` and then set the onclick event to `onClick={() => SetMsg("1")}` and I'm back to the error I posted above.